# TFS check-in error: Could not find a part of the path

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, nuget, nuget-package

Our team works on a project with TFS as source control. Sometimes that I want to check-in some errors happen.

`D:\CustomManager.1.0.7184.35750\lib\net461\CustomManager.dll: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\CustomManager.1.0.7184.35750\lib\net461\CustomManager.dll'.`

I gotta go to the `Packages` folder and make a new folder. after that, I have to copy the previous version of the package in that and then rename it to solve the case. This way is a little annoying because sometimes after that, new errors will show with different versions.

Additional information: This error will only be shown when I update the NuGet packages.
Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Stop putting binary packages into source control. Use a NuGet repository.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you directly checked libraries(dlls) in to TFS and manage version control of them.

It's **not a recommend way**, there are multiple downsides such as it's never exactly clear which projects are using which versions of which assemblies. It's a maintenance nightmare.

Suggest you use **Nuget** to handle these libraries in TFS. You should compile your code, package it in Nuget and publish it. For multiple projects you can upgrade their nuget references when appropriate, or stick with the older versions if they need to. If you need to reference a known-good, stable version, you just make sure your project is configured to pull a specific version from NuGet.

TFS use Package Management that hosts NuGet, npm, and Maven packages alongside all your other TFS assets: source code, builds, releases, etc, also be able to handle the external packages.

You could add external packages to a TFS Package Management feed. When you restore the packages, select the feed. All need packages will be restored entirely. To achieve this, just use [Push NuGet packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/package/nuget#push-nuget-packages) to specify the packages you want to publish and the target feed location.

More details please refer [Get started with NuGet Package Management in TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-nuget)

---

**Update:**

Keep looking for old packages, this will not happen if you already referred the latest dll in project. Please double check this part.

In your situation, if you want to check the dll in source control, you should add dlls in the solution/project and **use relative path**. Otherwise, tfs server may not find path.

For cache issue, suggest you to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) then restart VS, and check in again, this may do the trick.

Comment: I'm already using Nuget to install libraries. so I think the TFS process is right, but sometimes it can not find old packages (which is not needed now because they're updated) and it gives me an error, so I gotta make fake folder and packages to bypass these errors.

Comment: @MrBitmap Did you mean you still get this issue  `Could not find a part of the path 'D:\CustomManager.1.0.7184.35750\lib\net461\CustomManager.dll'` ?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the CustomManager via NuGet, but while checking in, it will give me an error that the previous version could not be found. It seems the TFS is looking for old packages somewhere in windows cache or something similar.

Comment: @MrBitmap Thanks for your quickly feedback. I need some time to do a test in my side and dig into this. If found any useful info which may narrow down the issue. Will update here.

Comment: Thanks for your response and your consistency.

Comment: Hi @MrBitmap I could not reproduce it. Have no idea why the solution/project keep looking for old packages. This will not happen if you already referred the latest dll in project. Back to the question, in your situation, if you want to check the dll in source control, you should add dlls in the solution and **use relative path**. Otherwise, tfs server may not find path. For cache issue, suggest you to [clear TFS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/) then restart VS,this may do the trick

Comment: Hi @MrBitmap Any update on this issue? Have you figured it out? If you do, please kindly share the solution here.